# only the last elif chunk gets executed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am stuck on a seemingly trivial problem for a while now.

I have a conditional loop where I get the user to enter a `raw_input` and assign variables based on the input entered.

Here is the code to make my explanation clear:

```
location = raw_input("Where are you located? : ")
#print (location)

if location == "London":
    recreationList = londonRec
    businessList = londonBus

elif  location == "California":
    recreationList = caliRec
    businessList = caliBus

elif  location == "Mumbai":
    recreationList = mumbaiRec
    businessList = mumbaiBus

....code to be executed based on location
```

The issue I face is that the code below only gets executed when I input mumbai as the `raw_input()`, every other time it loops back up to `"Where are you located?"`.

I feel that this is a really simple thing, that I am completely overlooking, any guidance is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Apart of course for indentation being wrong, there is nothing in your current code that could cause this behaviour. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `"mumbai" == "Mumbai"  # False`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This code doesn't run, due to undefined variables.  When I remove those and replace it with tracing statements, it works as expected.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should create your variables before assigning the values to them. This might solve your issue, i am not sure.  please refer to this [link](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) for further details in scope in python. Also, your indentation is incorrect.
try this code:

```
location = raw_input("Where are you located? : ")
#print (location)

recreationList = None
businessList = None

if location == "London":
    recreationList = londonRec
    businessList = londonBus

elif  location == "California":
  recreationList = caliRec
  businessList = caliBus

elif  location == "Mumbai":
  recreationList = mumbaiRec
  businessList = mumbaiBus

....code to be executed based on location
```

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't work because you haven't properly defined your variables.  They need to be predefined because python won't create the variable just from setting another variable equal to that variable.